# How to compare assignments in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following

```
it 'should assign a new profile to user' do
  get :new
  assigns(:user_profile).should ==(Profile.new)
end
```

But it's not working. I've tried 'eql?' and 'equal?' respectively. How do I compare it in order to know if the contents of @user_profile is Profile.new?

I used to do a workaround doing a .class of the assigned variable, checking if it's Profile but I want to stop with these bad practices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Object.new` invoked twice by design creates two *different* objects, which are not equal.

```
1.9.2p318 :001 > Object.new == Object.new
 => false
```

One thing you can do here is

```
let(:profile){ Profile.new }

it 'should assign a new profile to user' do
  Profile.should_receive(:new).and_return profile
  get :new
  assigns(:user_profile).should eq profile
end
```

Now you're not actually creating a new profile when the controller action is invoked, but you are still testing that `Profile` is receiving `new`, and you're testing that the return value of that method is being assigned by the controller to `@user_profile`.

Comment: awesome bro, that's just what I've wanted! ;-)

Comment: In fact there's no particular reason to make the value of `profile` be an actual `Profile` object; it could be anything. E.g., `let(:profile){ "a new profile" }` wouldn't really change the functionality of the test. But that's ok, because in a controller test you don't want to be testing the functionality of `Profile::new` itself. However, this could conceivably cause message expectation errors if additional methods are called on the `@user_profile` in the controller action. (Then another option would be `let(:profile){ mock('Profile').as_null_object }`.)